# How do you get the current value of an NSStepper in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

So I'm trying to build a timer app on macOS where a stepper is used to change the time, but I don't know how to get the current value of the stepper. I have maximum, minimum, integer, and increment values, but pressing the stepper doesn't actually change the value. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `floatValue`:

```
print(stepper.floatValue)
```

Comment: Isn't `doubleValue` preferred?

Comment: It's according to the requirement, could use intValue if that what is required.